# Destroy/dispose method on a Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

Do you need to have a destroy/dispose method on your Document Class?

Say I have a Document Class that has the following

```
- mouse event listeners
- timers running and or enter_frame listeners
- class variables
```

Do I need to have a destroy or dispose method that:

```
- removes event listeners
- stops timers
- nulls class variables
```

Or is this only something I need in other objects (sprites, movieclips) that are added to the stage of the Document class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you don't need to have such a method, because the object represented by the document class tends to live as long as your app is alive. However, that's not necessarily the case. For instance, if you have "stub" swfs, you may want to clean them up when they are unloaded. The caller can call unloadAndStop on the Loader that loaded your swf (for flash player >= 10), but it's still a good idea to clean things up, I think.

A simple way to do this is taking advantage of the ADDED_TO_STAGE and REMOVED_FROM_STAGE events. That is, whenever your object is added to the stage, do all the initialization you need. When it's removed, do your clean up. Something like this:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class YourDocClass extends MovieClip {

    public function YourDocClass() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,setup);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,cleanup);
    }   

    private function setup(e:Event):void {
        // your setup code here
    }

    private function cleanup(e:Event):void {
        // your cleanup code here
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to remove these two event listeners. In fact, if you just leave them listening for the event, you could reuse the object (sometimes it takes a little bit of extra care to keep your object in a consistent state, though; using a new instance is much simpler and generally the performance hit you take is not problem)

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, it's good to have a `dispose()` method if instances of your class are ever going to be "discarded." There's no `finalize()` in Flash (unlike Java) so you need a place to clean things up.

What needs to be cleaned up:

1. Running timers must be stopped
2. 'enterFrame' event listeners must be removed
3. Open network connections should be closed
4. Any children added to the stage must be removed
5. Stage event listeners must be removed
6. BitmapData objects must be disposed
7. Sound playing must be stopped

... and so on.

You can end up with serious memory leaks if you don't do so.